# You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Visible (Access.Application)

Tags: c#, ms-access

When I create COM object instance of Access application using `Interaction.CreateObject("Access.Application")`, then I am able to "use all features of Access" like setting `.Visible = true` or `.UserControl = true`, but when I start Access using EXE file and then when I am trying to get "attached" to that instance of Access using `Interaction.GetObject(null, "Access.Application")`, I am not able to perform `.Visible = true` nor `.UserControl = true`, because it throws an error:

> you entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Visible

I don't understand what's going on.

Anyway, this is the code I am testing this with:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string TEST_DB_PATH = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\db1.accdb";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic accessApp = null;
            try {
                accessApp = Interaction.GetObject(null, "Access.Application");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                accessApp = Interaction.CreateObject("Access.Application");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("accessApp: " + accessApp);
            Console.WriteLine("Version: " + accessApp.Version);

            accessApp.Visible = true;
            accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(TEST_DB_PATH);
            Thread.Sleep(750);
            accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
            accessApp.Quit();

            /*
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

So as said, when I create new instance of Access using the `CreateObject`, everything works. With `GetObject` COM object I can perform `OpenCurrentDatabase`, but I cannot perform `.Visible = true`, etc.

Windows 7 x64 Pro SP1, tried with Access 2007 and 2016 - same result on both versions.

Comment: So with GetObject Access application is already open and visible?

Comment: Well, yes, so setting the .Visible property to true is not really needed, but what's a bigger problem for me is that I can't call Application.DoCmd.SetWarnings(false) to prevent showing errors in a dialog form. If I was able to call SetWarnings(false), all problems Access might encounter would be thrown as an Exception, and that's something I can process in my program with try&catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

Once `UserControl` has been set to True, both `UserControl` and `Visible` are read-only and True.

You can work around this by testing if `UserControl` is true:

```
If(!accessApp.UserControl){accessApp.Visible = True;}
```

Comment: So basically such instance (started using the exe file) is useless - at least for me. Anyway thank you very much for pointing this out. In the meantime I discovered that I can use the CLSID of the app in order to create a new instance of specific Access version which perfectly suits my needs.

Comment: Well, you can do about 99.9% of all operations with an instance started by opening the exe. Some operations (like making the window invisible) are somewhat more difficult since you can't use the COM method for it and need to use WinAPI instead. Also, you don't need to hard-code CLSIDs to open a specific version, you can just use the version number on proper installations, e.g. `CreateObject("Access.Application.16")` to open the 2016 version or `CreateObject("Access.Application.14")` to open the 2010 version.

Comment: Yes, but I had troubles with that .Version suffix so I will play a little bit with CLSIDs. Also it's true that I can do almost anything with such instance, but it get a little bit tricker with Access as Access is disabling any VBA content when run as .UserControl = False. I would have to build a script for clicking the Options... button in TopBar, then hitting the "Allow" checkbox and clicking the OK button - unless there's a simpler solution I don't know about.

Comment: Nope, if VBA is disabled your options are suddenly very limited, now I understand your _basically useless_ statement, you don't have many options then. You can of course modify the registry to add the location your Access database resides at as a trusted location, but then you might get red-flagged for potentially malicious activity, messing with the trust center registry is not recommended.